# Why is my array not getting set?

Tags: cuda, pycuda

I am trying to teach myself CUDA. This has not been easy so far, but I don't give up easily either :)

I have created a very simple program. It merely returns a value from the GPU.

```
import pycuda.driver as cuda
from pycuda.compiler import SourceModule
import pycuda.autoinit
import numpy as np

returnValue = np.zeros(1)
mod = SourceModule("""
  __global__ void myVeryFirstKernel(float* returnValue) {
    returnValue[0] = 8.0;
  }
""")
func = mod.get_function('myVeryFirstKernel')
func(cuda.InOut(returnValue), block=(1024, 1, 1), grid=(1, 1))
print str(returnValue[0])
```

However, the value that my program prints is `5.387879938e-315`. That sure doesn't look like `8.0`. Why is the wrong value getting returned from the GPU?

I have tried altering the block size, which I don't think should anything (but who knows). I have also checked that the data type I am sending in (float64) matches my kernel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have type conflicts - your kernel is expected a 32 bit single precision value, but you are passing a 64 bit double value to it. If you rewrite your code something like this:

```
returnValue = np.zeros(1, dtype=np.float32)
mod = SourceModule("""
  __global__ void myVeryFirstKernel(float* returnValue) {
    returnValue[0] = 8.0f;
  }
""")
func = mod.get_function('myVeryFirstKernel')
func(cuda.InOut(returnValue), block=(1024, 1, 1), grid=(1, 1))
print returnValue[0]
```

so that everything is explicitly specified in single precision, you might have more luck.

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way I could get the kernel to accept float64s instead of changing my `returnValue` array?

Comment: That would depend on whether your GPU actually supports double precision or not. Not all devices do.

Comment: Ah Thanks! Apparently, mines does since `double* returnValue` works.